# Convert Dataweave 1 to 2 trying to generate same response

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

Here is the sample request and response along with the code used in Dataweave 1

```
    {
  "employees": [
    {
      "eId": "1",
      "email": "a@xyz.com",
      "uuid": null
    },
     {
      "eId": "2",
      "email": "b@xyz.com",
      "uuid": "abcd"
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected response is :

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "eid": "1",
      "email": "a@xyz.com",
      "uuid": null,
      "uuid": "abcd"
    },
    {
      "eid": "2",
      "email": "b@xyz.com",
      "uuidDetails": "abcd"
    }
  ]
}
```

In Mule 3 this is achieved with this code :

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json

--- 
results: (flatten (payload.employees map (value1,index) ->{
        "eid" : value1.eId,
        email: value1.email,

        ("uuidDetails": (value1.uuid) when (value1.uuid != null) 
            otherwise (payload[0].uuid)
        )       
    }))
```

In Mule 3 there is some amount of majic happening here:

> ("uuidDetails": (value1.uuid) when (value1.uuid != null)
> otherwise (payload[0].uuid)
> )
> #1
> if we do not enclose within () then the response for this section is :

```
 "uuidDetails": [
    null,
    "abcd"
  ]
```

#2 `otherwise` is behaving completely differently when its condition is satisfied , it generates an o/p without the key 'uuidDetails' and also neither an an object nor as an array

```
"uuid": null,
"uuid": "abcd"
```

I am struggling to achieve this in Mule 4 , was trying out a few things but no luck ....
Mule 4 code that is not producing desired o/p:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
results: 
                (flatten((payload."employees" map (value1, index) -> {
                    eid: value1.eId,
                    email: value1.email,
                    
                    (
                        uuidDetails: value1.uuid
                    )if ((not value1.uuid == null))  ,                    
                    (                        
                        uuidDetails: payload.employees flatMap ((item, index) -> item.uuid)
                    )if (value1.uuid == null)  ,
                })))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior in Mule 3 seems weird. In Mule 4/DataWeave 2 I needed to be more explicit to achieve the same result. Instead of cramming everything in one expression I used separated expressions for the null and not null cases. Having less 'magic' expressions makes the intention more clearer reading the script.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
results: 
    payload."employees" map (value1, index) -> ({
        eid: value1.eId,
        email: value1.email,
        (uuidDetails: value1.uuid) if (not value1.uuid is Null)
    } 
    ++ if (value1.uuid is Null) 
        {(payload.employees map ((item, index) -> uuid: item.uuid)) } 
    else {}
)
```

If `value1.uuid` is not null I use its value. If it is not null I create a separate object with all the key-values from the `uuid` in each element of payload.employees and then I concatenate it into the main object.

Note that your script has unneeded parentheses and uses flatten() and flatMap() but there is no need for them.